# C# list type conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a List(X) and List(Y). X and Y are  different classes with same properties. 
I need to convert an object of type List(Y) to an object of type List(X). The reason for the conversion is i need  to pass the list objects to a function to perform some operations, else i would have to repeat the code for each list type.

Comment: It is possible by inheritance with X and Y.

Comment: Try listOfXs.Select(x => new Y()).ToList();

Comment: The best way to do this if it's possible for you is to make an interface with these properties, have both classes implement this interface, and make the lists of that interface type.  Regardless, you'll probably want to read up on `covariance` and `contravariance` which is why inheritance doesn't solve the problem quite as easily as you might think with collections.

Comment: If the fields are same or similar, try automapper.